# Angular2 - Subscribe not firing

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement a shared service in order to share information between components.

In this moment, the subscribe doesn't work and I don't know why...

This is the service:

## service

```
private subject = new Subject<any>();

getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> 
    {

        this.subject.next({data:"test"});
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
```

## component

```
subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {


    this.subscription = this.authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(data => { 

      this.message = data;
      alert('I called the method');

    });    
  }
```

In this moment the execution didn't go inside the procedure that set the message and do the alert...

Thanks to support

Comment: Where do you provide this service to your components?

Comment: Is `getCurrentUser` the only place where `next` is called on the subject? If so, it's called before the `subscribe` - which means the subscriber won't receive a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you don't use the `Observable` the way it's meant to be used, an `Observable` is basically a data stream, and you're emitting the data before you subscribe to the stream.

```
private subject = new Subject<any>();

getUserObservable(): Observable<any> 
{
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}

setUser(user:any):void{
    this.subject.next(user);
}
```

In your tests:

subscription: Subscription;

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.authService.getCurrentUserObservable().subscribe(data => { 
      this.message = data;
      alert('I called the method');
    });
    // The subscription will be called right here.
    this.authService.setUser({data:"test"});
  }
```

Then, if you call `setUser` from another component, service or whatever, your subscription will be called.

Comment: Thanks Supamio, the call works but there is something strange...
If I log the data received in subscribe method, I can see the properly data valorized in the browser console but if I try to log a property of the received object like var a = data.firstName , I get "undefined"... This is very strange because if I navigate inside the full data object I can see the values...

Answer (score 2):

In your example/test try changing the Subject to a BehaviorSubject

```
private subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({date: "test"});
```

then change your getCurrentUser to

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
   return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

One big difference between a subject and behaviorSubject is that you have to provide a start value for the behaviorSubject, and it also emits the current value to you when you subscribe to it. A Subject will not emit its last set value to you when you subscribe, it will only start "watching" at the point you subscribe and pick up on subsequent changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your subject emits the value before you are subscribing. That's is how a subject works. You could use a `BehaviorSubject`. A BehanvoirSubject re-sends the value, but takes a default value:

`private subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);`

If that's is not what you want you could use a map:

`return this.subject.asObservable().map(value => !isNullOrUndefined(value))`